# What is meaning of # inAsp.Net,Asp.Net MVC3

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, c#-4.0, razor

For Silverlight # Symbol has a specific meaning. also in case of html and CSS.

but I haven't found the use in Asp.Net MVC 3

Please help me.

Comment: can you show an example?

Comment: What makes you think that the hash symbol (alone) must have some inherent special meaning in ASP.NET? Did you encounter this somewhere in your code?

Comment: As well as 3,777, 13, 42 have special meanings in some particular context- should all possible languages/context support special meaning for them?

Comment: I've never seen a more poorly formed question on StackOverflow ever, congratulations.

Comment: lol, I almost want to bump up this question just because it made me laugh...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The # symbal has no meaning in ASP.NET